# Using jQuery to remove all rows in a table after a specified row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'd like to delete all rows in a table after row x where x is a number that switches up. The following does not work:

```
$("#comps-table tbody tr:gt(x)").remove();
```

Nor does:

```
$('#comps-table tbody tr').gt(x).remove();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is a variable so you need to use string concatenation.

```
$("#comps-table tbody tr:gt(" + x + ")").remove();
```

or the preferred way is to use slice()

```
$('#comps-table tbody tr').slice(x).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var after = 5; // remove after row number 5

$('#comps-table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var rowNumber = $row.index();

    if ( rowNumber >= after ) {
         $row.remove();
    }
});
```

Havent tested it but it should put you in the right direction

Comment: True, plus it doesnt feel efficient. Arun P Johny's answer is more suitable  -cheers